# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context making a personal app

Tags: swiftui

This is my code when I add `TextField($order.name, placeholder: Text("Name"))`.

I get a error saying `"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"` on the line where I have `Text("Number of Cakes: \(order.quantity)")`.

My code :

```
Stepper (value: $order.quantity, in: 3...20) {
                            Text("Number of Cakes: \(order.quantity)")
                        }
                }

                    Section {

                        Toggle(isOn: $order.specialRequestsEnabled){
                            Text("Any special requests?")
                        }

                        if order.specialRequestsEnabled {
                            Toggle(isOn: $order.extraFrosting) {
                                Text("Add extra frosting")
                            }

                            Toggle(isOn: $order.addSprinkeles) {
                                Text("Add extra sprinkles")
                            }

                        }
                }

                Section {
                    TextField($order.name, placeholder: Text("Name"))
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI can, at the moment, often show errors that are quite a way off from the error site. These errors can show up both before and after the actual error and be completely unrelated to the real error. Best is to comment out all unnecessary code, or even create a simple example and get that working first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constructor in `TextField`, use instead

```
Section {
    TextField("Name", text: $order.name)
}
```